# How to load my silverlight user control step by step?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, load

how can i load my silverlight user control step by step? what we can see is one completes, after 1 second the other starts....  Thanks very much if can provide a demo.

Comment: Can you please clarify what it is you are actually asking? "One completes" "The other starts" makes no sense out of context.

Comment: Just like Win8 start, there have lots of cards in the page, we say mainpage, now in Win8 it is when you click a card and then will enlarge and display the detail content about this card, i don't want it like that, i want it no need to click card and the cards will auto turn over and display another style of card content, and the turn over animation need display step by step, means the first card turn over, and then the second, thrid...., do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a TransitionControl like this: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TransitionControl/FirstLook
Then you can manually set a timer in code behind to switch the content every second or so?